# Kubernetes Client API from Google Cloud Functions (Firebase) Token Refresh

Tags: firebase, kubernetes, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I want to start Kubernetes jobs on a GKE cluster from a Google Cloud Function (Firebase)

I'm using the Kubernetes node client https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript

I've created a Kubernetes config file using `kubectl config view --flatten -o json'

and loaded it

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromString(config)
```

This works perfectly locally but the problem is when running on cloud functions the token can't be refreshed so calls fail after a while.

My config k8s config files contains

```
          "user": {
              "auth-provider": {
                  "name": "gcp",
                  "config": {
                      "access-token": "redacted-secret-token",
                      "cmd-args": "config config-helper --format=json",
                      "cmd-path": "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud",
                      "expiry": "2022-10-20T16:25:25Z",
                      "expiry-key": "{.credential.token_expiry}",
                      "token-key": "{.credential.access_token}"
                  }
              }
```

I'm guessing the command path points to the gcloud sdk which is used to get a new token when the current one expires. This works locally but on cloud functions it doesn't as there is no `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud`

Is there a better way to authenticate or a way to access the gcloud binary from cloud functions?

Comment: You're correct that your current approach using `gcloud` locally to authenticate the `gcloud` user against the cluster.

Comment: The current approach also uses a being-deprecated auth mechanism.See [`gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar mechanism (using Cloud Functions to authenticate to Kubernetes Engine) albeit written in Go.

This approach uses Google's [Kubernetes Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest) to get the cluster's credentials and construct the `KUBECONFIG` using the values returned. This is equivalent to:

```bash
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...
```

[APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) has a Node.js [example](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/get#examples) for the above method. The example uses [Google's API Client Library for Node.JS for Kubernetes Engine](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) also see [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/container/index.html).

There's also a [Google Cloud Client Library for Node.js for Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/container/latest) and this includes [`getCluster`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/container/latest/container/v1.clustermanagerclient#_google_cloud_container_v1_ClusterManagerClient_getCluster_member_1_) which (I assume) is equivalent. Confusingly there's [`getServerConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/container/latest/container/v1.clustermanagerclient#_google_cloud_container_v1_ClusterManagerClient_getServerConfig_member_1_) too and it's unclear from reading the API docs as to the difference between these methods.

Here's a link to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/9506c0b9677d53a3e11b7457ed21cbe7) containing my Go code. It constructs a Kubernetes `Config` object that can then be used by the Kubernetes API to authenticate you to a cluster..